# Where to buy a SIM card in Cape Town

Tags: cellphones, cape-town

Where is the easiest place to buy and activate a pre-paid SIM card in Cape Town after arriving at CPT airport?

Are there any special requirements? (A local address, etc)

Comment: To whomever voted to close this: 1) This is not a price-shopping question. Notice nothing in the question asks about price at all. 2) It is not opinion-based, where SIM cards can be purchased is not a matter of opinion, but a matter of fact. (I suppose there might be some matter of opinion in the term "easiest", but I believe that is a reasonably objective qualifier to put on a question)

Answer (score 1):

I was in South Africa earlier this year and rented a SIM card for my iPhone 5 at the Vodacom store in the Johannesburg Airport. You should be able to go into any mobile store off the street and buy a prepaid SIM card for your device. Make sure your device is unlocked and able to be used with another carrier other than the carrier you originally bought it through.

**Location:** 
Vodacom Shop 
Gardens 
Cape Town 8001 
South Africa

The only information I needed were my passport, home address, credit card, and contact information. They made copies of both my credit card and passport for their records.